# Getting document name using REST (not title) while filtering document library

Tags: rest, filter

I am trying to filter through a list and return metadata of the documents in that filter.  How do I return the name of a document from a document library using REST while being able to filter the document library?  I can bring back the title field, but that isn't always the name of the document.

I tried doing a select all in my query and still couldn't see it.  The closest I can get is `_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/Items(2)/FieldValuesAsText`.  If I query this then I can get the name of the item.  However, I'm not sure how to do this while filtering the list.

My original query is `_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Title,Category,ReviewDate&$filter=ReviewDate ge  'today'`.

Comment: For filtering on name you can use `web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{document library name and folder path }')/Files?$filter=Name eq '{document name}'`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### How to retrieve document name using SharePoint REST

Since `FileRef` contains file name, you could utilize the following query to return document names:

Endpoint: `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=FieldValuesAsText/FileRef&$expand=FieldValuesAsText`

**Example**

Get documents (names) that have been created from 2014 year:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=FieldValuesAsText/FileRef&$expand=FieldValuesAsText&$filter=Created ge  datetime'2014-01-01T00:00:00'
```

Comment: @vadim filter data in SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online is not always same way. I am trying to filter by filename its not happening in SharePoint Online. Please advice, Thanks,  $filter=substringof('publishdoc-prod.js',FileRef) ist not Working SPO but good in On Prem. Tried : /Files?$filter Name eq {'publishdoc-prod.js'} in SPO , but no luck.

Comment: @ShivendraPatel : i have used below query in SP Online and its working 
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Doc Library Name')/items?$select=FileRef&$filter=substringof('Test Document Name',FileRef)";

Answer (score 14):

FileLeafRef:

```
 /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('list')/items?$select=FileLeafRef
```

File Name:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=File/Name&$expand=File
```

Also, for querying a document library by Name of document, use below:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Doc Library Name')/items?$select=FileRef&$filter=substringof('Test Document Name',FileRef)";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/_api/web/Lists('ListGUID')/items?$select=FieldValuesAsText/FileRef&$expand=FieldValuesAsText&$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'filename.txt'
```