# REST - how to get item ID and document name while filtering by a Lookup field?

Tags: document-library, rest, lookup-column, filter

I am trying to query a document library via REST and get the item ID and the document name.  The query needs to filter on a (single value) lookup field.

Originally I was using a CAML query to do the filtering on the lookup field, which worked, but that only returned `SPListItem` objects, which have the ID, but that means I would need to do another REST call to retrieve the `SPFile` objects to get the document name.

I came across [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/126015/8992) which solved the problem of getting the ID and document name with one call by using OData `$select` and `$expand` options on the `FieldValuesAsText` property.

I also came across [this other answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/118659/8992) about how to filter on a Lookup field if you know the lookup ID (which I do).  It basically says that when a Lookup field is added to a list, the lookup IDs are accessible via a property named `LookupFieldName` + `Id`, so: `MyLookupFieldId`.

My REST query looks like this:

```
"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Doc Lib Name')/items?$select=ID,FieldValuesAsText/FileLeafRef&$expand=FieldValuesAsText/FileLeafRef&$filter=MyLookupFieldId eq " + lookupId;
```

However, the filter is not working.  I get an error:

> Column 'MyLookupFieldId' does not exist. It may have been deleted by
>   another user.

Oddly, if I do `$select=ID,MyLookupFieldId,FieldValuesAsText/FileLeafRef` with no filter, the response does contain a property named `MyLookupFieldId` with the correct lookup ID.

So what's going wrong here?

I found [yet another answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/132711/8992) which has a comment that seems to imply that filtering on a lookup field by ID is not supported on-prem, but that question is also about multi-lookup fields, and mine is a single value lookup field.

So is that the case?  Is OData filtering on a Lookup field not supported on-prem regardless of single or multi lookup?

If so, how can I get what I want?  Is it possible to combine a CAML query and OData query so I can use CAML to filter by the lookup field, but OData to expand the `FieldValuesAsText/FileLeafRef` to get the document name?

**How can I get the `SPListItem` ID and the `SPFile` document name, while filtering by a Lookup column, all in *one single REST query*?**

Comment: Is it SharePoint online or SharePoint OnPremise?

Comment: It is SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

Comment: Can you please try "MyLookupField" or "MyLookupField/ID" instead of MyLookupFieldId and try once.

Comment: @Sam I had tried both of those previously and they didn't work.  I did figure it out though, see below.

Comment: Please check my edited comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, yet again, another one of those times when you discover the answer yourself a mere five minutes after posting the question.

It works if you explicitly expand the lookup field you are trying to filter on, like so:

```
"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Doc Lib Name')/items?$select=ID,MyLookupField/Id,FieldValuesAsText/FileLeafRef&$expand=FieldValuesAsText/FileLeafRef,MyLookupField&filter=MyLookupField/Id eq " + lookupId;
```

Answer (score 0):

When filtering, you take the Id off of the lookup (ONLY in the filter). I use the same syntax as your original example in your question, but filter should look like: `..."&$filter=MyLookupField eq " + lookupId;`. I'd suggest using that rather than expanding it.